# Package managers cause kernel freeze?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, skype, freeze

I'm having this serious problem about package management. Whenever I try to install something (anything) it cause system to permanently freeze. It's worse than it looks, Ctrl+Alt+F1 not working and even Alt+SysRq+REISUB doesn't work!

#### Possible problem triggers

- E4rat
- Skype

I highly suspect skype because the very first crash happened when I tried to install it, it did some progress and then my PC got freezed, it's freezing ever since (whenever I try to install something via apt / dpkg / Ubuntu Software Center).

I might be wrong, maybe the first freeze happened because of something else and forcing computer to reboot corrupted the file system, so maybe trying to access required package-related files make system crash.

**Example:**

```
$ sudo apt-get install synaptic
E: dpkg kesintiye uğradı, sorunu düzeltmek için elle 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' komutunu çalıştırın.
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Last line cause permanent freeze.

I desperately need some solution, any help is welcome !

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include (a link to) the content of your `/var/log/dpkg.log`.

Comment: @David Actually I solved this a long time ago and I don't have access to that computer anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by E4rat. I realized it after running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` command in TTY1 (Ctrl+Alt+F1) which gave me kernel debug info (or whatever the messages are).

Changing grub configuration back to it's original state solved the problem.

First I edited grub file with this command:
`gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`

Then changed this line:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="init=/sbin/e4rat-preload quiet splash"`

To this:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

So we stopped e4rat from initializing the system which was the problem.

Hope this will help someone in future...